# How do I change the microphone input sensitivity on iPad 2?

Tags: audio, ipad, microphone

Is it possible to change the microphone sensitivity (input volume) on the iPad?

If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

What you can do with the built-in microphone is limited. You should investigate purchasing a third-party microphone, or better yet an audio interface with a microphone preamplifier, into which you plug a microphone. This will cost money but give you much more control.

Look for products from [Tascam](http://tascam.com/applications/recording/iphone/), [Apogee](http://www.apogeedigital.com/products/mic.php), [Line 6,](http://line6.com/mobile#mobilein) [IK Multimedia](http://www.ikmultimedia.com/products/cat-view.php?C=mobile), and [Griffin](http://www.griffintechnology.com/ipad/av).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to change the microphone sensitivity system wide on the iPad 2 and above, but only for external mics, as far as I know.

To adjust the audio input level you need two things:

- Apple's $5,- GarageBand (I don't know about free apps that can adjust the mic level)
- An external microphone: either attached to the the mini jack (headphone connector, like Apple's own white earbuds) or attached to the Apple 30-pins or Lightning connector using the USB adapter of the camera connection kit or the Lightning-to-USB adapter cable.

In the voice recording section of GarageBand, select the button with the audio plug. With a supported device you should see the audio-input level slider and other extra settings like a monitor switch. The microphone input level adjusted in GarageBand, works system wide.

Depending of the amount of current you USB-mic needs, it could be that the iPad cannot deliver sufficient energy to power the mic. In that case you can use the Griffin iMic, or a powered USB hub.
My Samson C01U works perfectly without any additional power requirements.

Comment: "The microphone input level adjusted in GarageBand, works system wide."  That's bizarre, but I tested it and it's true.  So there's no other way to adjust input level from within the Camera/video app, for instance?

Comment: Yes, there are other free apps that can adjust it.  Voice Record Pro by Dayana Networks is one.  Confirmed that adjusting the level in there adjusts it system-wide, though it's a clunky way to do it.  So there's at least one, but probably others that are better.